# Check to see if a list given as input contains at least 1 int and no more than 6

Tags: python, string, int

So I am wondering how to check and see if the list given from the user input has at least 1 int and no more than 6 ints in the list. If there is at least 1 and no more than 6 it should return true, and anything else it should return false. This is what I have so far. I am a little confused on how to compare the list to 2 different values.

```
def checkList(aList):
    if any(x>= 1 for x in aList) and any(x <= 6 for x in aList):
        return True

    else:

        return False
```

the first any(x>= 1 for x in aList) works but if I type more than 6 ints into the string for the input, it still returns a true value when it should return a false value. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `number_of_ints = sum(1 for i in aList if isinstance(i, int))`

Comment: Do you maybe just want `1 <= len(aList) <= 6`? It’s unusual to have lists with mixed types. (If they’re stored as strings or if you’re trying to distinguish numbers with a fractional part, it makes more sense.)

Comment: I agree with @minitech that you may want to separate validating the input type from validating the input length. This will lead to more informative error notifications to the user (if you currently fail what are you going to tell him?)

Comment: @minitech YES! This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If the list is of different types, the following will work:

```
def checkList(aList):
    num_ints = map(type, aList).count(int)
    return num_ints >= 1 and num_ints <= 6
```

Comment: `return 1 <= map(type, aList).count(int) <= 6`

Comment: That would be better actually, just that little bit more concise.Thanks!